# How can I convert string of boolean to boolean?

Tags: javascript

Consider an example

```
"true"  ---> true
"false" ---> false
```

How can I do this in JavaScript? Please help

Comment: what if the string is `"wibble"`? I mean "true" === "true" is true and "false" === "true" is false ... but so is "wibble" === "true"

Comment: No the string will be either "true" or "false". I need to remove the string to make it boolean. How to do I do it

Comment: well, check if it equals the string `"true"` - or JSON.parse("true") JSON.parse("false")

Comment: well it works! But is there any way to achieve the same via operator

Comment: operator ... yeah ... `===` is an operator

Comment: What about simply `if( myVariable === "true" ) doSomething()` ?